# How to find where/why a view is resized?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, size

I have a view (actually, a UIControl) as part of my UIViewController.  This view is designed in IB and then in the code, based on some user's actions, I'm changing the view's frame.  The whole thing is happening inside CATransition.  The code looks like this:

```
CATransition *anim = [CATransition animation];
anim.type = kCATransitionFade;
anim.duration = 0.5;
anim.delegate = self;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

[mainPanel.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];

float totalHeight = ...; // this is the Y of the frame
float max_width = ...;   // this is the width of the frame
float bh = ...;          // this is the height of the frame

... //some computations to determine the frame for my view

[blockView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, totalHeight, max_width, bh)];

//This is for debugging
CGSize sg = answer1.frame.size;
NSLog(@"width: %f, height: %f", sg.width, sg.height);
//This outputs: width: 260.000000, height: 29.000000
```

So far everything is fine and in the NSLog I see the correct values for width and height.  Yet, when the view is displayed, its dimensions have changed.  I then added the same debugging to `animationDidStop` - and see different results:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [scroll flashScrollIndicators];
    CGSize sg = answer1.frame.size;
    NSLog(@"width: %f, height: %f", sg.width, sg.height);
    //This outputs: width: 280.000000, height: 49.000000
}
```

Note that somewhere somehow the size of the view has changed.  I can't get my head around where/why/how this may be happening.  Any ideas where else to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding when the view is resized you could subclass the uiview and override the following

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

now this function will be called each time the view changes its size

Comment: That's one way of doing it, however seems like a bit too much work. Subclassing UIControl, changing my code and changing the NIB, all to just to find who/when calls one of the methods.  I may have to do that though if I can't solve it in any other way.

Comment: Hope you find it in an easier way, but this is the faster way i know of

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll have to go this route.  I'll accept the answer as it's definitely valid.